# Pandas: get row content after certain word

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm using pandas (Python) to extract some data from an excel sheet. 
Currently I have written a code which goes through each column and if it finds a text it returns me the whole column:

```
def getTextData(self, dataframe, getText):

        for col in dataframe:
            for cellvalue in dataframe[col]:
                if getText == cellvalue:
                    #print dataframe[col]
                    return cellvalue
```

However I can't figure out the following problem: 
I only want the row content after the word "getText" to be returned.

Can someone assist please ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
print df
   a  b
0  a  b
1  f  v

print df['a'].str.contains('a')
0     True
1    False
Name: a, dtype: bool

print df[df['a'].str.contains('a')]
   a  b
0  a  b

print df.b[df['a'].str.contains('a')]
0    b
Name: b, dtype: object
```

EDIT:

IIUC you can use [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
 print df
   a  b
0  a  b
1  f  v
2  i  k

print df['a'].str.contains('a')
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: a, dtype: bool

print df['a'].str.contains('a').shift().fillna(False)
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: a, dtype: bool

print df[df['a'].str.contains('a').shift().fillna(False)]
   a  b
1  f  v
```